# How to use nested forms in rails on some pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I can not understand how to user nested_forms with belongs_to assosiation
I have in /views/posts/show.html.erb this form:

```
 <%= form_for([@post, @post.reviews.build]) do |review_form| %>
      <%= review_form.text_area :body, class: "form-control" %>

      <%= review_form.fields_for :post do |f| %>
       <%= f.text_field :final, class: "form-control" %>

       <% end %>
      <%= review_form.submit "Add review" %>
    <% end %>
```

and i need when user submit form text :final going to post table

controllers/reviews_controller.rb

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @review = @post.reviews.new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @review = @post.reviews.build(review_params)
        if @review.save
            redirect_to post_path(@post)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    private

    def review_params
        params.require(:review).permit(:negative, :post_id, :body, :user_id, :for_user_id, post_attributes:[:final]).merge(:user_id => current_user.id)
    end
end
```

models/review.rb

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :post
end
```

and when i submit form rails given Couldn't find Post with ID=41 for Review with ID=
but when i delete this accepts_nested_attributes_for :post from review model i dont know how create strong parameters
Please help

Answer (score 0):

`accepts_nested_attributes_for` should be in the post model, not in review. Something like:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :reviews
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :reviews, allow_destroy: true
end
```

therefore, should be also changed `<%= review_form.fields_for :post do |f| %>` into `<%= review_form.fields_for :reviews do |f| %>`

because post has a lot of reviews and post should accept nested attributes of reviews

Comment: thank's but this code create this Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"h+TxQ/jlFx4k1mbQ+27ytbL7DDAWIXQWCa5WGZTp1G0=", "review"=>{"body"=>"11111", "negative"=>"1", "user_id"=>"14", "for_user_id"=>"1", "post"=>{"final"=>"1111111111111", "status"=>"3"}}, "commit"=>"", "post_id"=>"41"}
but we need to create post_attributes

Answer (score 0):

You seem have your controllers and forms mixed up. Assuming a post must exist in order to create 1 or more reviews try this instead

**form to add to the post show page**

```
<%= form_for(@review) do |review_form| %>
  <%= review_form.text_area :body, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= review_form.fields_for :post, @post do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :final, class: "form-control" %>
   <% end %>
  <%= review_form.submit "Add review" %>
<% end %>
```

**Posts Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @review = @post.reviews.build
  end
end
```

Hope that helps